# Can I run eg artisan commands without having to type php

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

OK, so I realise this is a bit lazy. :-) But I'd like to be able to run Artisan commands without having to type the "php" part. So just `artisan migrate` instead of `php artisan migrate` for example.

Is it possible to "install" artisan like this? Or do I just have to live with typing the four extra characters?

PS - yes, I know I just typed hundreds of characters to ask how to save typing four characters. :-) But I only have to ask once ... and if someone has an answer, I can save typing four characters hundreds of times.

My main dev box is a Mac with El Capitan 10.11.6, but I also use Ubuntu and RedHat in VMs, test servers, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac you can create bash aliases. Edit `~/.bash-profile` hidden file which is in your user's directory. In case if you're using zsh then edit `~/.zshrc` file.

Here's my file which creates couple of aliases:

```
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
alias a="php artisan"
alias am="php artisan migrate:refresh --seed"
export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

So, when I run `a make:model`, it runs `php artisan make:model`. When I enter `am` command, `artisan` refreshes all migrations and seeds the data.

Comment: Cool ... so I could just do eg `alias artisan="php artisan"` and that should do it for me.

Thanks! And of course I can probably do something similar in Ubuntu if I spend a minute or two googling.  :-)

Comment: Beautiful! I added `alias artisan="php artisan"` and `alias seed="php artisan migrate:refresh --seed"` to `~/.bash-profile` on my Mac and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: ...and according to [this askubuntu page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) and [this redhat.com page](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2006-October/msg00041.html) I can add `alias artisan='php artisan'` to `~/.bashrc` on Ubuntu and RedHat to get the same effect. Cool.

Comment: this also works on windows with git installed (C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\bash_profile.sh). If you edit the file you have to run it as administrator though (vs code prompts you upon saving)

Answer (score 3):

You also could use a "Shebang" line instead of creating aliases. Just place the path to your php interpreter on top of your artisan file.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

// ...
```

Now you can call the artisan file directly and the correct interpreter will be loaded.

Maybe you have to add execution permissions to your artisan file.

```
chmod +x ./artisan
```

Comment: Thanks - yes, I can see that working too. Of course I'd have to tweak my artisan file and re-tweak if ever it gets updated ... but that's not too much of an effort.